# Android BLE connection issue after pairing

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

How to reconnect to a BLE device that has been already paired?
The following steps were followed and the connection is faulty. The BLE device keeps connecting and disconnecting all the time. If the device is manually unpaired before I reconnect again, it works. So I assume there is a problem when I am trying to connect to a BLE device that has already been paired.

step1: Scan for device(lescan)
step2: Connect to device after found(BluetoothGatt)
step3: Create Bond (Device.CreateBond())
step4: Discover services

Are there any differences that need to be followed when I am trying to connect to a device that has been already paired?

Comment: If anybody used to have this problem, and solved it, please comment the solution...